Как создать много серверов с помощью WebSocket для мультиплеерной онлайн игры?
В одной мультиплеерной онлайн игре есть 5 игровых комнат. Начать играть можно, подключившись к одному из ip адресов из списка(всего таких ip адресов около 10 с разными портами). В игре сотни тысяч игроков.
Если учитывать, что на одном ip адресе с одним портом можно создать 1 слушающий веб-сокет, который будет принимать запросы от 100 игроков, то как создать много серверов с помощью WebSocket на 10 ip адресах? Возможно ли это? Или существуют другие способы?

Непонятно в чём вопрос, создать много серверов можно точно так же, как и один сервер, просто повторить много раз

Ну и надо понимать, что один сервер может держать несколько коннектов на разных портах, так же как и за каждым портом может стоять отдельный сервер. Под сервером, я понимаю экземпляр ПО, а не физическую машину

@andreymal есть 10 физических серверов, на каждом можно создать игровые сервера с разными портами.  Но в игре, про которую идет речь на каждом из физических серверов доступно только 3 порта: 4201, 4202, 4203. Это около 300 игроков, но в игру играют сотни тысяч игроков. Вот я не понимаю как возможно создать тысячи игровых серверов (1 сервер - 1 слушающий вебсокет), имея всего 10 физических серверов и 3 порта.

Откуда ограничение на 3 порта? Откуда ограничение на 100 игроков?

@andreymal Я проверял в игре разные порты, они доступны, но кроме меня на таком сервере никто не играл. На счет 100 игроков я наверное не прав, их даже меньше на сервере.

Если вы пытаетесь разобраться в том, как работает уже существующая игра, то тогда вопрос не имеет смысла, нужно спрашивать непосредственно у разработчиков игры, что и почему они сделали. Чисто теоретически ничто не мешает иметь условно бесконечное число игроков на условно бесконечном числе серверов, запущенных на всего одном порту — лишь бы оперативки хватило

@andreymal на 1 ip и 1 port можно привязать только 1 слушающий сокет. Вот в чем проблема.

И этот 1 слушающий сокет может принадлежать прокси-серверу, который перенаправит подключение на любой другой сервер из условно бесконечного их количества, никакой проблемы в этом нет

@andreymal Спасибо! Вероятно так и есть.

А ещё я чувствую необходимость упомянуть unix-сокеты, которые позволяют сокету слушать не порт, а файл — и таким образом даже ограниченное количество портов не является проблемой, если прокси-сервер будет перенаправлять соединения на файлы unix-сокетов, которых может быть условно бесконечно много. Проблемой это всё может стать, когда физический сервер перестанет тянуть возложенную на него нагрузку, но тут уже нужно на конкретном проекте исследовать, какую нагрузку он создаёт и сколько пользователей способен потянуть один сервер без потери производительности
